# Página web que se vea igual que en un computador pero mas pequeña en un tablet o celular

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, responsive

Necesito que una pagina web que utiliza check, select, text y botones se pueda ver en tablets o celulares de la misma forma en que se ve en un computador normal pero más pequeña como si se hiciera un zoom automático.

En otras palabras que se vea de tamaño reducido o bien con zoom. NO debo usar media querys o crear paginas responsivas.

La página esta diseñada para que sea vea en computadores normales en una intranet no en celulares pero en casos extraordinarios si se ve desde un celular se necesita que se vea igual pero a menor escala o más pequeña.

Se utiliza bootstrap con el único fin que se vea más agradable a la vista en computadores normales.

Llevo horas buscando y no logro dar con la respuesta, ya que la mayoría aconseja usar mediaquerys, hacer página responsiva, etc. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe una etiqueta *meta* etiqueta que se añade en el *header* de las páginas responsivas, para que su contenido se ajuste correctamente (con fluidez) a las pantallas de dispositivos más pequeños de acuerdo al CSS de las *media-queries*:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Si la omites, o las propias media-queries, cuando cargas la página en una pantalla de un dispositivo móvil, se verá la *versión web*, pero ajustándose al tamaño de la pantalla, es decir la misma versión, pero de menor tamaño, o al revés, es decir la versión móvil en pantallas grandes pero con codos sus elementos a escala según el tamaño de la pantalla.

Comment: Como usamos bootstrap para embellecer la página utilizábamos esa meta etiqueta, una vez que la quitamos se comporto de la forma deseada, gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

No me parece que hacer zoom sea la mejor opción, pero bueno, si se puede:

js

```
document.body.style.zoom = "70%";
```

css

```
body {
    zoom: 70%;
}
```